# Pair two data frames with conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, random, matching, combinatorics

I have two data frames (a and b), each with only two columns: ID and SID. I want to make **random** pairs of IDs between the two data frames with one restriction: pairs cannot share SID. This is an example of what I want, but the real data contain thousands of IDs and many many shared SIDs. I take it I will use zip at some point. No clue what else to do...

edit: also, a solution must allow for data frames of unequal length (some IDs may go unpaired).

```
# The data

a = {'ID':['tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'SID':['hal', 'pete', 'zen', 'bop']}
b = {'ID':['tim', 'sasha', 'alex', 'jose'],
        'SID':['hal', 'kora', 'zen', 'felix']}

# One possible output
print(ab)

tom sasha
nick tim
krish jose
jack alex
```

Comment: how many pairs of output are you expecting? (e.g. a given number or "as many as possible")  should each `ID` only appear once in the output?  note that the efficiency of solutions will depend on lengths of these structures, as well as the statistical distribution of number of `ID`s per `SID`, more details would help

Comment: @SamMason As many pairs as possible. Odds out are acceptable. Each ID should only appear once - that is, each 'person' should only have one partner, again, provided they do not share the same SID. For the purposes of this question, let us assume that there are nearly twice as many IDs as SIDs.

Comment: it's sounding a bit like a combinatorial optimisation problem, i.e. something that can't be done in a single pass.  given the sparsity of the constraints you might be able to get away with doing something naive, but I doubt you'd be able to get close an optimal solution in a single pass.  hopefully that's given you some terms to read about, if you add some working code to your question that might give me some ideas. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for what's a good level of detail

Comment: I've modified your tags around to help other people find this question.  you didn't have any language so I added Python as that's what it looks like, hope that's right!